# Cannot convert 'Tree**' to 'Tree*' in assignment

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-tree

I am trying to create a program for a class at school that takes an input and puts it into a binary tree. When i compile i get the error "Cannot convert 'Tree**' to 'Tree*' in assignment". It compiles if I comment out the InsertNode method.

```
//The main method to create the tree
void CreateTree()
{
    char list[MAX_SIZE];

    string line;
    getline(cin,line);
    strcpy(list,line.c_str());
    cout << list << endl;

    Tree* root = new Tree;
    root->data = list[0];
    root->right = NULL;
    root->left = NULL;

    for(int i=1; i<MAX_SIZE; i++)
    {
        InsertNode(root, list[i]);
    }

}

//The method to insert the next char into the tree
void InsertNode(Tree* root, char n)
{
    Tree* curr = &root; //the error is here
    if(curr==NULL)
        curr->data=n;
    else if(curr->data<=n)
    {
        curr=curr->right;
        InsertNode(root, n);
    }
    else if(curr->data>n)
    {
        curr=curr->left;    
        InsertNode(root, n);
    }
}
```

I realize that some of the other code may not work as intended, but i would just like help on the error i am receiving.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
Tree* curr = &root;
```

you need

```
Tree* curr = root;
```

`root` and `curr` are supposed to be pointers-to-Tree (i.e. their type is `Tree *`). But `&root` means "the address of `root`" which would therefore be a pointer-to-a-pointer-to-a-Tree (i.e., a `Tree **`).  The error message is telling you that you can't interchange the two types `Tree *` and `Tree **`.